# Is there any straightforward simplification for the attached DC-Circuit

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

Simplifying a DC circuit would start by collecting the parallel resistors or the ones in series, for this circuit, I do not see any simplification, Am I right?

My end goal is to calculate the values of V and A as the values of R1 and R2 and RL are known, (0 Ω, 100 kΩ, and 30 kΩ respectively).

[image]

---

What about the diagram below, is it similar to the one above?

What are the values that will be displaying on Voltmeter and Ammeter for R1= 0 Ω, R2= 100 kΩ, and RL= 30 kΩ?

PS: RL is considered to be a fixed resistor.

[image]

Comment: You've written, "0,100 Kilo_Ohm and 30 kilo_Ohm respectively". Is that a German-style "0.100" or did you omit a space and mean "0 ohms, 100 kiloohms and 30 kiloohms" (note lowercase 'o' for ohm)? If R1 is 0 ohms then the problem is trivial. Note that HTML entities work in the post (but not in the comments) and you can use `k&Omega;` for \$ k\Omega \$.

Comment: @Elliot, I've just rolled back an almost identical edit I made. The OP said, "R1 and R2 and RL are known, (0,100 Kilo_Ohm and 30 kilo_Ohm respectively" so there must be three values in there: 0, 100k and 30k. They should have been written 0 Ω, 100 kΩ and 30 kΩ.

Comment: @Transistor I guess we needed a mutex somewhere in there. I just couldn't let "Kilo_Ohm" be seen by other readers.

Comment: @Transistor, Yes I meant (R1=0 Ω, R2=100 kΩ, and RL=30 kΩ which is a fixed resistor)

Comment: Your initial 0.1 kohm ( assumed for R1,2) is now 0 & 100 kohm is not even close to a typo or even described as a variable.

Comment: Yes, I have fixed the typos.

Comment: They were major changes Ohm’s Law tells you for R1=0 , Vo=Vs . That is too trivial even to be a question. A meters are 0 ohms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are looking for the Thevenin equivalent voltage source. V<sub>S</sub>, R1 and R2 can be replaced by a voltage source with the value \$ V = \frac {R_2} {R_1 + R_2}V_S \$ and a series resistor of \$ R_S = \frac {R_1 R_2}{R_1 + R_2} \$.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case Vs~10 V and Rs=0. Therefore, the value of A measured by ammeter would be A=V/R=0.0003 A and if we measure the Voltage across RL, we find 10 V as the source.

Comment: My equations still hold. If R1 = 0 Ω then Rs = 0 as calculated by my second equation. The current (we use ***I***, not 'A') would be given by \$ I = \frac V {R_L} = \frac {10}{30k} = \frac 1 3 \ \text {mA} \$ which agrees with your calculation.

Comment: The voltmeter would display 10 V across the resistance RL?

Comment: Yes, if R1 is 0 Ω then how could it be otherwise? I note that you haven't addressed the confusion in the comments. Can you fix your question, please?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question. Thank's for your remark!

Comment: Good job. Is everything clear then? If your question has been answered then don't forget to accept the one that helped you most.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your actual question: If you assume that the ammeter and voltmeter are **ideal meters** then they have no affect on the circuit: there is zero voltage across the ammeter and zero current flows through the voltmeter. In this case, \$R_2\$ and \$R_L\$ are **parallel**. The voltage across these two resistors will be the same. Once you know the voltage across these two resistors, the current through \$R_L\$ is just that voltage divided by the resistance of \$R_L\$.

In other words, an ideal ammeter can be replaced with a short circuit (a wire) and an ideal voltmeter can be replaced with an open circuit.